# how to disable and enable Design view Rename delete cut copy when right click on Tables forms

Tags: ms-access-2007

we have a program made in Access with extension .mdb and sql server forms reports macros modules in access Tables and scanning documents storage in sql sever
1- how to disable and enable Design view Rename delete cut copy when right click on Tables forms ...
2- is there any vba code for scanner feeder for scanning documents from access form storing in sql server

[image]